# The cardinality of all the infinite binary sequences that don't contain 010

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Find the cardinality of all the infinite binary sequences that don't contain 010

I think it's $\aleph_0$. 
I marked the set all infinite binary sequences that don't contain 010 in A, and the set of All the infinite binary sequences that don't contain 01 in B. $B\subseteq A$, and $|B|=\aleph_0$, therefore $\aleph_o\le|A|$. But I don't know how to show that $|A|\le\aleph_o$ .
Thanks

Comment: Consider the set C all sequences made up of 11 and 00. Such sequences cannot contain 010. What do you think its cardinality is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not $\aleph_0$, but rather $2^{\aleph_0}$, as it contains all 0-1 sequences of the form
\begin{equation}
  x_1x_1x_2x_2x_3x_3x_4x_4\ldots
\end{equation}
where $x_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I don't know of any standard meaning for $\aleph$. What does it mean here?

Comment: I apologize, I have meant the cardinality of the continuum: $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection from the set of all binary sequences to the set of all sequences not containing `010`: just replace all occurrences of `01` with `011`. And the cardinality of the set of all binary sequences is...?